# Stop paypal access token from refreshing so frequently

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Straight forward and simple question;

What is the best way to stop PayPal access token from refreshing so frequently?

I have tried to do curl command with extended 'expires_in': command. Doesn't work. Still refreshes after 24hr

Comment: PayPal decides when those tokens expire.  Not you.

Comment: So is there a way to continuously request one on the back end so I dont have to constantly change my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access tokens are temporary and usually refresh after 9 hours. They can be cached for that period of time (the response will have an expires_in), but apart from that you need to requet a new one as soon as the one you have is set to expire.

This is by design and intended. There is no way to change it.

Comment: Following this answer, I created a function to request an up-to-date / new access token every time someone places an order.